# JS/HTML - Removing item before querying again

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code that grabs images from an API and it all works fine however, I can't figure out how to remove the original query before the other is displayed.

Open to other methods as well.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>Stock History Graph :</div>
    <form>
      <input type="text" value="" id="imagename"/>
      <input type="button" id="btn" value="Update" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
        var val = document.getElementById('imagename').value,
            src = 'http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=' + val +'.AX'+'&t=6m&q=l&l=on&z=s&p=m50,m200"',
            img = document.createElement('img');

        img.src = src;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the img variable outside of the onclick function, then in the onclick function all you have to do is set the src of the image.
Right now you're creating a new element every time you click the button.

Comment: Thanks for the response, seems really obvious now. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Check if Image already there just update src, no need to create tag again.

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  var val = document.getElementById('imagename').value,
      src = 'http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=' + val +'.AX'+'&t=6m&q=l&l=on&z=s&p=m50,m200"',
      img = document.getElementById("chart-comp") || document.createElement('img');
      img.id = "chart-comp"
      img.src = src;
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fen8jd0/)

Comment: Thanks heaps, works perfectly and now i feel dumb by how obvious that was. Cheers